# помогите с расстановкой знаков препинания

Tags: пунктуация

На вопрос "Как сердцу высказать себя?", ответ, скорее всего, – никак.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (зеленая галочка).

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов: **На вопрос: "Как сердцу высказать себя?" – ответ, скорее всего:  "Никак".**

**В качестве образца:**

(1) Папа читал что-то и на вопрос мой «Бывают ли синие зайцы?»,  не поднимая головы, отвечал: «Бывают, мой друг, бывают».    Несогласованное определение: только кавычки.

(2) Папа читал что-то и на вопрос мой: «Бывают ли синие зайцы?» – не поднимая головы, отвечал: «Бывают, мой друг, бывают».
    Обычное оформление прямой речи (тире после вопросительной прямой речи).

Comment: Большое спасибо!